# How can I make an extension for a list of lists

Tags: c#, arraylist, extension-methods

I want to make an extension for a list of lists, if possible. I've tried variations on this theme, but none worked:

```
public static List<List<myClass>> ToListsOfmyClass(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<OtherClass>> listsOfOtherClass)
{
    return listsOfOtherClass.SelectMany(many => many.Select(p => new myClass(p)).ToList()).ToList();
}
```

I receive the following compile error:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List>'    SSX.Revit.Access    D:\SourceCode\WorkSpaces\AllProjects\SSX.Revit\r2020 (v.20)\Startup (plugin)\v1.0\SSX.Revit.Access\Support\AIMPoint.cs  67  Active

Comment: How to make it work, if possible.

Comment: Probably your Return Type doesn't mach. With SelectMany you destroy the Inner List, you return only a List<myClass> I would assume. If you want a List of List, change SelectMany to Select.

Comment: @Holger I was afraid of that. Any other options for making such an extension work? I can rephrase the question if needed.

Comment: @Fabjan  like... return listsOfXYZs.Select(many => many.Select(p => new AIMPoint(p)).ToList()).ToList();

Comment: We don't know what "Works" is. Either you change the return type,or you change the query. They don't fit.

Comment: @Holger fair enough. I mean take a List<List<type>> and return List<List<othertype>> as an extension method. So per your point, I want to change the query to work. But perhaps Fabjan and you solved it above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that the myClass(p) works fine as I use it elsewhere.

This fact is completely irrelevant to the actual problem, the error message should be along the lines of:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<T>>'
```

As we said in comments you could modify your method to return `List<List<T>>`:

```
public static List<List<myClass>> ToListsOfmyClass(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<OtherClass>> listsOfOtherClass)
{
    return listsOfOtherClass.Select(x => x.Select(p => new myClass(p)).ToList()).ToList();
}
```

Or add another method where we flatten the collection and return `List<T>`:

```
public static List<myClass> ToFlattenedListsOfmyClass(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<OtherClass>> listsOfOtherClass)
{
   return listsOfOtherClass.SelectMany(x => new myClass(p)).ToList();
}
```

As an aside, in number of scenarios, where for example we have 1000 classes like this I'd consider adding a generic method or using a tool like `AutoMapper`. For example:

```
public static List<List<To>> ToListsOfmyClass<From>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<From>> listsOfOtherClass) where From : IMyConvertible
{
   return listsOfOtherClass.Select(x => x.Select(p => p.Convert<To>()).ToList()).ToList();
}

interface IMyConvertible { ... }
```

This would require `From` to implement method `.Convert` from interface `IMyConvertible`

Comment: Actually, I ended up using an extension method I already have: return listsOfOtherClass.Select(x => x.ToMyClass()).ToList();